# VF Page Column Labels

Tags: visualforce

I have a aggregated class as below
snippet below

```
public list<AggregateResult> getLastTopInfos () {
    return [SELECT Account__r.Name aaa, SUM(value__c) bbb, Account__r.Strategy__c ccc
            FROM Info__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') AND Value__c > 0
            Group By Account__r.Name, Account__r.Strategy__c
            Order by SUM(value__c)  DESC
            LIMIT 10
    ];
}
```

---

```
<apex:pageBlock title="InfosbyAccount" rendered="{!IF(LastTopInfos.size>0,true,false)}" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!LastTopInfos}" var="h" border="2">
        <apex:column value="{!h['aaa']}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!h['ccc']}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!h['bbb']}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Its displayed as below without any column header

Account1   strategy1  Value1
Account2   strategy2  Value2
and so on..................
Account10  stratgey10 Value10

How can I include the column labels and have the VF page rendered as below

AccountName StrategyName  Value
Account1    strategy1     Value1
Account2    strategy2     Value2
and so on..................
Account10   stratgey10    Value10

Comment: Here is the example. Slightly different in case of AggregateResult http://www.alokagrawal.com/blog/archives/74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apex:facet` inside `apex:column` to display header as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="InfosbyAccount" rendered="{!(LastTopInfos.size>0)}" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!LastTopInfos}" var="h" border="2">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">AccountName </apex:facet>
                    {!h['aaa']}
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">StrategyName  </apex:facet>
                    {!h['ccc']}
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Value </apex:facet>
                    {!h['bbb']}
        </apex:column>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Refer [apex:facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm)